# How to address chinese character in force.comIDE

Tags: visualforce, ide

I am facing very odd issue.  When  force.com IDE sync code from online to IDE, if vf page/class include Chinese character, all is good. if i modify some Chinese character in vf page/class  and click save button, SFDC online will display garbage code.

I already setting eclipse font size for utf-8 and build for utf-8, but still not working .

if you konw it, please tell me.

Many thanks

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get the right eclipse version --- eclipse java developer